# Does switching phones also let you take your purchased apps to the phone you are switching over?

Tags: lumia, apps, settings

I am using Nokia lumia 1020 with windows 8.1.10.

Thinking to buy Lumia 132. So when I sign in by my Microsoft account in 1320, Would I also get all my purchased apps in that also?

```
Does switching phones also let you take your purchased apps to the phone you are switching over?
```